# Problem with object made from joining objects that both had mirror modifiers

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

1. I have joined a mirrored object to another mirrored object (head and body, creating neck to join them) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) and I am trying to connect them by creating vertices (tried extruding/merging or pressing f to just fill). I have selected one vertices from each object to create edge then with four of those I can create a face. But when I try the face or edge is created on the other side of the mirror not on the same side any solutions without removing the mirror. (shown below)

[image]

2. I would like to move parts of the mesh around from where I selected, but when I try to move it it is controlled from the left side and only the left side (the original mesh). I was able to do this before (move parts of the mesh from both sides) I don't know why I can't any more maybe from the update, any solutions? An example for more detail if I try to drag the right side out it inwards becuase I am moving it from the left side not the right side that I selected

Comment: disable clipping and move them where you want then enable it again

Comment: Don't know which problem this one was for but both still occur.

Comment: it would be easier if you can upload the .blend file it's hard to get the full idea from a picture

Comment: and i meant the top vertices or flip the top object on the X_axis and it's better to work with the mirror disabled in the edit mode to see the real vertices

Comment: it's ok, did you try the last comment ?

Comment: Sorry I tried flipping it but the outside of the head goes in the middle and looks wrong. I went to mesh mirror and x-axis. Update I just had to move it back in place sorry. First problem is fixed but is there a way I could move the mesh from the mirrored side as well (problem 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You merged objects mirrored but not moddeled on the same side. You can see that by deactivating the visibility of the modified topo.

[image]

to fix that, apply the mirror (in object mode, not edit)

[image]

In front ortho view (NumPad<kbd>1</kbd> front view, NumPad<kbd>5</kbd> to switch perspective/ortho view) Box select <kbd>B</kbd> one side.

[image]

Delete selected vertices with <kbd>X</kbd>

[image]

add the mirror modifier that should work correctly

[image]

Comment: Is there a way when I select the mirrored side the manipulator will go there as well instead of going to the original side.

Comment: nope, the manipulator appears where the real selected vertices/edges/faces are, even if you select the mirrored ones.

Answer (score 2):

disable the Mirror in edit mode to see the original verticies :

[image]

the two part are not on the same side and that wat cosed the crossed faces

- select the top part
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and mirror along X-axis
- move the mesh to the right position
- now you can bridge them

[image]